# mysql query to identify change of state

Tags: mysql

I posted an updated question on [mysql query, return rows when condition is satisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279891)

Thanks to those who helped...

Ok, I'm taking a second stab at this, because I messed up my original question.  I've corrected the date format to match mysql.  In addition, I actually was derviving the state value in a query based on percentage of the value, i.e. if it was within 85% of highest observed value it gets marked as high, if its within 15% of Low watermark then its marked Low.

Its format is name, test_date, score.

So something like

```
John, 2014-10-12, 87
John, 2014-10-13, 87
John, 2014-10-14, 33
John, 2014-10-15, 32
John, 2014-10-16, 44
John, 2014-10-17, 87
John, 2014-10-18, 89
John, 2014-10-19, 90
Jane, 2014-10-12, 32
Jane, 2014-10-13, 87
Jane, 2014-10-14, 33
Jane, 2014-10-15, 88
Jane, 2014-10-16, 44
Jane, 2014-10-17, 87
Jane, 2014-10-18, 89
Jane, 2014-10-19, 90
```

Here is the query I currently have to return data that is only within high or low watermark.

`select userdata.name, test_date, score, if(score >=.85*temp.High,"High","Low") 
from userdata 
inner join (select name, Min(score) as Low, Max(score) as High 
from userdata where (test_date between '2013-12-02' and '2014-12-01') group by name) 
as temp on userdata.name=temp.name where (score >= .85*temp.High or score <= 1.15*temp.Low)
and test_date between '2013-12-02' and '2014-12-01' order by name, test_date`

Assuming highest was 96 and lowest was 35 this returns data such as

```
 John, 2012-12-02, 90, High
 John, 2012-12-03, 40, Low
 John, 2012-12-04, 41, Low
 John, 2012-12-05, 95, High
 John, 2012-12-05, 94, High
 John, 2012-12-02, 90, High
 Jane, 2012-12-03, 40, Low
 Jane, 2012-12-04, 41, Low
 Jane, 2012-12-05, 41, Low 
 Jane, 2012-12-06, 41, Low
 Jane, 2012-12-06, 41, Low
 Jane, 2012-12-11, 89, High
```

Now I'd like to see if I can modify my query to only return the state of changes.  I looked at the answers provided, but I'm out of my element in combining them with my original query to produce the desired results.  Thanks for the help already given, and I apologize for not phrasing my question correctly the first time.

Comment: I hope those dates are in a `DATE` column.

Comment: Yes. And when they are, let us know

Comment: Yes they are, so I should have written them as YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: And that's why they made an edit button

Comment: I changed the question, I thought about resubmitting, but thought this would be best approach.  Basically I need to know how to mix the answers into my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using MySQL variables.

Whenever date is not matching and condition is not matching you can flag that row

You need to sort the rows by name and date so that adjacent dates are compared.

[`SQL Fiddle`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37a469/7)

```
select name,  prevDate, prevCondition
from
(
select name, `date`, `value`, `condition`,
       case when `date`<> @prevDate  and `condition` <> @prevCondition 
       then 1 
       else 0 
       end as flag,
@prevDate := date AS prevDate,
@prevCondition := `condition` AS prevCondition
from table1, ( select @prevCondition:= NULL , @prevDate = NULL) as t
order by name, `date` )T
where T.flag =1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with variables or by getting the previous state.  Here is the second approach:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.state
              from onetable t2
              where t2.name = t.name and t2.date < t.date
              order by t2.date desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_state
      from onetable t
     ) t
where prev_state is null or prev_state <> state;
```

For performance, you want an index on `onetable(name, date, state)`.